# Partial model match in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a table in my db and I am connecting it to a Django model using "managed=False". The thing is I don't want all 300 columns on that table. I only need two or three column, can I create a model with db_table pointing to that table but not defining all columns?
Appreciate your time in advance.

Comment: Why is it so problematic to add the extra columns? Django can create models with the `inspectdb` utility https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models

Comment: There are 350 columns, I don't have a use for all of that, and there are many tables like this ...

Answer (score 0):

I realized Django accepts multiple model definitions, with multiple columns in the different apps for the same project.
I had a very large table and I could manage it and make any query by only defining a subset of columns I needed. I did that even twice in two different apps of the same Django project. Please note that I used the Meta value of "managed=False" to keep my data safe from any unwanted Django Alter migrations. You can do the same if your table is managed by another application and you are only connecting to it for some data readings.